# setSkipWebLineCount(...) doesn't seem to be working on MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, radar-chart

I've been trying to implement a Radar Chart using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), and I'm just trying to make it look a little neater by skipping every other line. Documentation shows radarchart.setSkipWebLineCount(1) should do the trick, but the method doesn't seem to even be available. Has anybody else run into this problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the library? Which version are you using?

Comment: Yep, I feel stupid now. I'm pretty new, bear with me! Changed from V2.1.3 to V2.1.6 and all was well! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are using the [**latest version of the library**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases).

This should be the issue since this was just recently released in v2.1.6 - you should then find the method you mentioned.